# Server registering client ID twice for Socket() call

Tags: c#, sockets

Whenever I connect to the server using `Socket(127.0.0.1, port)`, the server listens and finds the client. But the problem is that the server registers it as two clients with two different IDs. When I close the client both of the IDs are closed together.

I can't seem to find what seems to be causing this double registration. I hope someone here can find the cause of this, I've had no luck. :(

Code for Listener.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace SERVER {
class Listener
{
    Socket sock;

    public bool Listening
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public int Port
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Listener(int port)
    {
        Port = port;
        sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (Listening)
            return;
        sock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0, Port));
        sock.Listen(0);
        sock.BeginAccept(callback, null);
        Listening = true;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (!Listening)
            return;
        sock.Close();
        sock.Dispose();
        sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    void callback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket sock = this.sock.EndAccept(ar);
            SocketAccepted(sock);
            if (SocketAccepted != null)
            {
                SocketAccepted(sock);
            }
            this.sock.BeginAccept(callback, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public delegate void SocketAcceptedHandler(Socket e);
    public event SocketAcceptedHandler SocketAccepted;

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem could be in that you're calling the SocketAccepted delegate twice:

```
        SocketAccepted(sock);
        if (SocketAccepted != null)
        {
            SocketAccepted(sock);
        }
```

Comment: That was the problem, I've checked through it so many times and couldn't spot it! Thanks bud.

Comment: Hmmm.. I don't remember unaccepting? o.o, re-accepted thanks for letting me know! @doogle